# android:Null pointer Exception

Tags: android

I have been developing an app and fair prediction is a part of it.. it contains a webpart too.. but i cant login into that part.. the app is terminating by that time.. the login page is linked to a jsp page and inturn to a mysql database.. i m posting the code here.. pls help me.. thanks in advance..

### Tlogin.java

```
package com.example.tracemeendpointsjson;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TLogin extends Activity  {

    EditText uname,pwd;
    Button log,signup;
    String response="";
    NameValuePair v;
    String LoginID,LoginPassword;
    HttpRequestClass mynetworkclass;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> namevaluepair;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tlogin);
        uname=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
        pwd=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwd);
        log=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        signup=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignup);
        log.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                LoginID=uname.getText().toString();
                LoginPassword=pwd.getText().toString();
                //CommonClassForLogin q=(CommonClassForLogin) getApplication();
                //q.myUID=LoginID;

                String url="http://"+details.ip+"taxinew/mobile/login.jsp";

            new AsyncTaskLogin().execute(url,LoginID,LoginPassword);


            }
        });

    }
    public class AsyncTaskLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>  
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mynetworkclass=new HttpRequestClass();
            namevaluepair=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",params[1]));
            namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",params[2]));

            try {
                String result=mynetworkclass.getinformation(params[0],namevaluepair);
                Log.d("dsfwewerte", result);
                result=result.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //Log.d("222222222", result);

            if(result.equals("0"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Welcomes You", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Trip.class);
                startActivity(in);

                //Log.d("11111111111", result);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Wrong Entry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent in1=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
                startActivity(in1);

                //Log.d("0000000000", result);

            }




        }



    }

}
```

### the HttprequestClass is as follows

```
package com.example.tracemeendpointsjson;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HttpRequestClass {
    HttpClient httpclient;
    public String getinformation(String url,ArrayList<NameValuePair> namevaluepair) throws ParseException, IOException
    {
        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request=new HttpPost(url);
        request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepair));
        try
        {
            HttpResponse respnse=httpclient.execute(request);
            int status=respnse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(status==200)
            {
                HttpEntity e=respnse.getEntity();
                String data=EntityUtils.toString(e);
                return data;
            }
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;

    }


    public String getsingleinformation(String url) throws ParseException, IOException
    {
        httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request=new HttpPost(url);
        try
        {
            HttpResponse respnse=httpclient.execute(request);
            int status=respnse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if(status==200)
            {
                HttpEntity e=respnse.getEntity();
                String data=EntityUtils.toString(e);
                return data;
            }                               
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;

    }
}
```

### the manifest file is as listed below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tracemeendpointsjson"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/traffic"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
           <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tracemeendpointsjson.Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".UploadDetails"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CurrentLocation"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GmailLogin"></activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".MailReceivers"></activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".ShowWeather"></activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".DisplayWeather"></activity>
          <activity
            android:name=".Trip"></activity>
           <activity
            android:name=".ShowRoute"></activity>
           <activity
            android:name=".Parking"></activity>
            <activity
            android:name=".Estfare"></activity>
             <activity
            android:name=".GetFare"></activity>
           <activity 
               android:name=".TLogin">
           </activity>
           <activity
            android:name=".ParkingPlaceShow"></activity>

        <service android:name=".ServiceClass" >
        </service>

      <!-- <service android:name=".GPSTracker"></service> -->  

    </application>

</manifest>
```

### the logcat output:

```
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at com.example.tracemeendpointsjson.TLogin$AsyncTaskLogin.onPostExecute(TLogin.java:85)
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at com.example.tracemeendpointsjson.TLogin$AsyncTaskLogin.onPostExecute(TLogin.java:1)
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-20 09:51:30.866: E/AndroidRuntime(476):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 09:51:30.896: W/ActivityManager(83):   Force finishing activity com.example.tracemeendpointsjson/.TLogin
03-20 09:51:31.428: W/ActivityManager(83): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{40803618 com.example.tracemeendpointsjson/.TLogin}

03-20 09:51:33.555: E/InputDispatcher(83): channel '40800e70 com.example.tracemeendpointsjson/com.example.tracemeendpointsjson.Home (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
03-20 
09:51:33.555: E/InputDispatcher(83): channel '40800e70 com.example.tracemeendpointsjson/com.example.tracemeendpointsjson.Home (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

---

Login.jsp is as follows:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : login
--%>
<%@page import="javax.swing.JOptionPane,DB.DbCon"%>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject" %>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONArray" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>


<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
String username=request.getParameter("username");
String password=request.getParameter("password");

JSONObject jo= new JSONObject();
//JSONArray ja=new JSONArray();
String query="select * from Userdetails where name='"+username+"' and pwd='"+password+"' ";

DbCon o=new DbCon();
ResultSet rs=o.selects(query);
         if(rs.next()){
             jo.accumulate("0", true);

         }

       else
                     {

        jo.accumulate("1", false);
               }

     out.print(jo);


%>
```

Comment: try to check null for `result` also as : `if(result !=null && result.equals("0")){..your code here}else{..your code here}`

Comment: My guess is that the `doInBackground` returns null. Check whats happening in doInBackground -check whats going wrong there.

Comment: where is `onPreExecute()` in AsyncTask ? Please add it. It will throw null pointer till you won't add it.

Comment: Please check firstyou get respnse or not????? afer that process aheade

Answer (score 2):

Try these code.. I think these is the problem.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String result;
        mynetworkclass=new HttpRequestClass();
        namevaluepair=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",params[1]));
        namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",params[2]));

        try {
            result=mynetworkclass.getinformation(params[0],namevaluepair);
            Log.d("dsfwewerte", result);
            result=result.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
        return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `result` is null, a simple change to your if-condition could solve this problem

```
if("0".equals(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to return the `result` in your `doInBackground` method at the end besides null. At the end of that method you are returning null that is why its throwing the `nullpointer excepection`.

Or you need to check for the null value of the result in your `onPostExecute` method to prevent the exception to be thrown.

> ```
>  @Override
>     protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         mynetworkclass=new HttpRequestClass();
>         namevaluepair=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
>         namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",params[1]));
>         namevaluepair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",params[2]));
>         try {
>             String result=mynetworkclass.getinformation(params[0],namevaluepair);
>             Log.d("dsfwewerte", result);
>             result=result.replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
>         return result;
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
>         return result;       <----- Check this line.
>     }
>     @Override
>     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>         super.onPostExecute(result);
>       //Check for the result is null or not.
>        if(result != null)
>        {
>              if(result.equals("0"))
>              {}
>         }
>    }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can Return `result` `"with No data"` with `default` and match it, you can also debug and check your Response what you get

Comment: thanku all for your valuable suggestions.. now the app is not force closing.. But it doesnot go to the second class that is trip.class though the value returned from login.jsp is 0(true)..